# Should TLS1.2 changes be made for TCP Socket communication on LAN?

Tags: c#, vb.net

We are migrating our applications to communicate in TLS1.2. We understand that TLS1.2 will be the standard going forward. We have identified all the applications that communicate to the thirdparty web services and use HTTP communication. However we have few applications which communicate using sockets(Client and Server on LAN). My question here is, since the client and server are on the private network and the application is using Sockets to communicate, Should i make code changes to use TLS1.2?

Comment: Yes.  Do not assume that attackers cannot get on your network.

Comment: Even though your network is private, it still may be sent over public networks.  You could be working from home and still connect to private network.  Most private networks encrypt their data and then send encrypted data over commercial networks.